# Why isn't my class's init function running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I'm struggling with understanding the __init __ function for a class when calling another file. This has been asked a lot, and I must be having an off day, because I can't get this to work at all! Well, I take that back.. if I only use __init __ or don't use it at all, it works. it's probably something dumb and obvious that I'm missing - Here's what's up ::

#### Folder Structure

- root

  - controller

    - __init __.py
  - main.py

### File 1 - main.py

```
from controller import appkey , appconf
# log file gets created in here #
app_process = appkey.generate(logfile)
```

### File 2 - controller.__init __.py

```
from public import printlog

class appkey(object) :
    def __init__(self,logfile) :
        self.logfile = logfile

    def generate(self) :
        printlog.log( message = f'Generating runtime key for application instance.'
## <<<< ERROR HAPPENS HERE | AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'logfile' >>>> ##
                , file = self.logfile ### <-- 
                , level = 'info' )

        try :
            <<<< stuff >>>>
            return run_ , key_
    except :
      <<<< mayday | exit >>>>
```

Visual Studio shows `self: 'runtime/application_logs/12072021-122743'` as a variable once entering the controller.__init __.py file, but it never becomes "self.logfile".

I appreciate the feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Your `__init__()` never gets called, because you never actually create an instance of the class - you're calling `.generate()` on the class itself.  You should have something like `appkey(logfile).generate()`.

Comment: YOU GUYS ALL ROCK!!! thank you, as soon as SO let's me mark an answer, i will. First come first serve since you all said the same thing. This actually makes sense. I appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not creating an `appkey` object anywhere, you are attempting to call `generate` on the *class itself* (not an instance of the class).   You are also passing `logfile` to the `generate` method when you should be passing it to the constructor.

You can change your code in `main.py` to this or something similar:

```
# Call the constructor first to create an appkey object, named 'a'
a = appkey(logfile)
# Now call generate on it
app_process = a.generate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to first create the class object, then call the `generate` method in `main.py`.

```
from controller import appkey , appconf
# log file gets created in here #
appkey_obj = appkey(logfile)
app_process = appkey_obj.generate()
```

You are setting the value of `self.logfile` (ie. the `logfile` instance variable`) when you create the object. Since it is an instance variable, you do not need to pass it into the` generate` method.

You are getting that error because when you pass `logfile` into `generate`, the `self` argument in `generate` is being set to the `logfile` string value. `self` is also an instance variable that will refer to the object itself when nothing else is passed in. However, since you are passing in `logfile`, `self` is set to `logfile` and it tries to call (basically) `logfile.logfile` (ie. tries to call an instance variable of the string).

Comment: small typo in your example, the last line should say `appkey_obj.generate()`  (not `appkey.generate()`)